# Checkbox form array data Vue 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a checkbox list which is generated using a for loop that consists of an id and a name:

```
Data:
yards[{id:1,name:'test'}] etc

HTML:
<ul class="checkbox-list">
     <template v-for="(yard, index) in yards">
                                <li>
                                    <input type="checkbox" 
                                        v-bind:id="'yardlist_'+yard.name"
                                        v-bind:value="yard.id"
                                        v-model="newSchedule.yards.id">
                                    <label v-bind:for="'yardlist_'+yard.name">{{ yard.name }}</label>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <input type="text" 
                                        class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="Yard notes..."
                                        v-model="newSchedule.yards.notes">
                                </li>
                            </template>
                        </ul>
```

I want to save the selected checkbox with the id and notes field in an array:

```
newSchedule: {
            due_at: '',
            notes: '',
            users: [],
            yards: [{id:'',notes:'']
        }
```

I have tried using the index from the yards array: newSchedule.yards[index].notes but am getting the following error **"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newSchedule.yards[index].id')"**

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

** Update **
Here is a basic fiddle of what I am wanting to achieve:
https://jsfiddle.net/j7mxe5p2/13/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to mix the old jQuery or javascript way of doing things with Vue framework. You should not have to set `id` on `<input>` elements to capture or set its value.

The correct way to do this is as follows:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            yards: [
                {id: 1, name: 'test', selected: true},
                {id: 2,name: 'test 2', selected: false},
                {id: 3,name: 'test 3', selected: false},
                {id: 4,name: 'test 4', selected: true}
            ]
        };

    },
    template: `
        <div class="list-of-yards"> <!-- You cannot use v-for on the top-level element -->
            <label for="jack" v-for="yard in yards">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="yard.selected"> {{yard.name}}
            </label>
        </div>
    `,
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle of the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/z48thf9a/

Things to note:

1. You cannot use `v-for` on the template tag itself
2. You cannot use `v-for` on the top-level element just inside template. The template should contain one and only enclosing element, typically a `<div>`
3. There is no need to set `id` on input elements. You need to use `v-model` for your model-view bindings

If you still have issues, please provide a jsFiddle to debug further.

**Edited after comment #1 and #2:**

My above response is focused more on constructing the Vue component and rendering the list with proper binding to the checkboxes.

To get the checked items into a separate array, you can use a computed property in the same component to run through the original array `this.yards` and create a new array of selected items only.

Here is the jsFiddle for capturing the checked values: https://jsfiddle.net/z48thf9a/1/

You may modify the above to capture only the `id` part, and rename `selectedYards` to `newSchedule` or whatever your app requires.

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, and if this solves your issue. Can you please provide more code samples?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, not sure if you read my question correctly though. I am generating the checkbox list from an array of data (yards), when the checkbox is checked I want to store that Id into another array (newSchedule.yards)

Comment: And straight from the Vuejs documentation:
Similar to template v-if, you can also use a <template> tag with v-for to render a block of multiple elements. [link]https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Template-v-for

Comment: @Pedro My apologies, I did not realize that template tag can be used for list rendering, as I never had to use it till now. Is it possible to create a jsFiddle or a complete code sample (with the full Vue component) that helps to debug this issue?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, here is an example of what I am trying to achieve (not working): https://jsfiddle.net/j7mxe5p2/13/

Comment: Sorry about the delayed response... There is some logical error in your `v-for` loop: your `yards` has 2 elements, but your `newSchedule.yards` has only one element. Therefore in the second iteration of v-for loop, you end up with `undefined` for `newSchedule.yards[index].id`. You will have to redo the logic in that area.

Comment: Using the `index` of one loop on a different array does not seem to be a good idea. It will work only for parallel arrays, that have exactly the same length and are logically connected. Your `yards` and `newSchedule.yards` are not parallel arrays. If I understand right, `newSchedule.yards` is a subset of `yards`? If so, the length of newSchedule.yards will always be shorter than length of `yards`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yards is a list of yards that can be selected in the form. newSchedule.yards is where I want to store the yards that have been selected form the list. i.e if they check yard with id 1 then I want that to be stored in the newSchedule.yards array, but I also need the option of attaching notes to this selected yard.

Comment: I still feel the index is running out of array length which needs to be corrected first. Can you install https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools in your chrome browser and see the values of `newSchedule`, `yards` and other data objects you may have?